# How to configure Apache NiFi with WSO2 IS for SSO

Tags: wso2, apache-nifi, wso2-identity-server

I have integrated NiFi with Apache Knox but I'm not getting how to integrate NiFi with WSO2 IS using SAML2. How can I integrate Apache NiFi with `WSO2 Identity server` using SAML for SSO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Nifi now we can configure SAML. Found [a resource](https://bryanbende.com/development/2021/02/17/apache-nifi-saml-keycloak) related to this.

To quote from the resource:

> In order to perform any type of authentication, we first need a secured NiFi instance. There are already many posts that cover this topic, so the starting point will be assuming that you can configure NiFi with a keystore, truststore, and https host/port.

Comment: This is correct. I have connected NiFi 1.15.2 with SAML 2.0 based authentication service.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like, NiFi doesn't support SAML authentication. But support the OIDC flow. Refer to [this](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#openid_connect)

So to integrate with WSO2 IS, you can create a [service provider with OAuth](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-oauth2-openid-connect-single-sign-on/) in WSO2 IS side and set up with the NiFi. You can also refer to [this](https://bryanbende.com/development/2017/10/03/apache-nifi-openid-connect), which explains how to integrate the OIDC with NiFi using google as an example. Here only different with the WSO2 is how the OAuth application is created.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!!, Can we change the source code for SAML authentication, what changes it requires.

Comment: We can't change the SAML authenticator code and make it support. You can use SAML for application - IS flow and oauth flow for IS - NiFi flow

Comment: Sorry I mean can we enable SAML authentication in nifi by changing source code of Nifi.